# How to resolve orphan case?

Tags: java, android

I have used the OnActivity Result code in which I have used switch statement but I got an error in `case 2`

```
switch (requestCode) {
case (1):
    //Code for camera
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        break;

        case (2):
        //Code for Gallery
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri photoUri = data.getData();
                if (photoUri != null) {
                    try {
                    currentImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                             this.getContentResolver(), photoUri);
                    selectedImage.setImageBitmap(currentImage);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        break;
    }

    //imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat results as well. It will be easier to find out the error.

Comment: Care to share the error with us?

Comment: What do you mean by "error in `case(2)`" - does this compile? I can't even see a `switch` declared anywhere

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: the indentation should hint that `case 2` is in the wrong block.... also hard to understand that inside a switch you check the value again ( `if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST` - here `requestCode` MUST be 1, otherwise this `if` will not be executed at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `case` inside if

```
switch (requestCode) {
    case (1):
        //Code for camera
        if (requestCode == Activity.CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        }
        break;

    case (2):
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri photoUri = data.getData();
            if (photoUri != null) {
                try {
                    currentImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), photoUri);
                    selectedImage.setImageBitmap(currentImage);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        break;
}
```

Comment: May as well use `case(CAMERA_REQUEST)` for the first `case` as well

Comment: and remove the first  condition from the `if`

Comment: @PPartisan I'm not sure what the int represent in this case. Obviously it's an `enum` from `Activity`, but the OP checks `if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)` in both cases.

Comment: i got the solution i just need to remove one bracket from the code and my code is working properly

Comment: i actually closed the switch statement after one case is completed and the other case is outside the switch switch (requestCode) {
    case (1):
        //Code for camera
        if (requestCode == Activity.CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        break;                              now it works fine